# Java: how can I use Jsoup to extract a particular data from html?

Tags: java

Basically, I am trying to extract the current price of a stock from this [link](https://www.google.com.hk/finance?q=0023&ei=yF14VYC4F4Wd0ASb64CoCw)

By looking at the page source, I want to be able to extract the number from this:

```
<meta itemprop="price"
        content="31.40" />
```

This is my Java code.

```
public double getCurrentPrice() throws IOException{
        String url = "https://www.google.com.hk/finance?q=0023&ei=yF14VYC4F4Wd0ASb64CoCw";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element content = doc.getElementById("meta");
}
```

And I kept getting this error:

```
456.0Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Element cannot be resolved to a type

    at application.Trade.getCurrentPrice(Trade.java:45)
    at application.Trade.main(Trade.java:64)
```

The error message is not very helpful. How should I overcome this ?

Comment: did you import `org.jsoup.nodes.Element`?

Comment: I did `import org.jsoup.*` . Is this not the same ？

Comment: @mynameisJEFF also `getElementById` is not correct it's a tag name.and `import org.jsoup.*` is different . it only import classes in org.jsoup pakage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import correct classes. also meta is not a id but a tag .so you can't use `getElementById` to get that element.using `itemprop` attribute get this element and get value by `content` attribute .

wildcard only imports classes from the package.for example

`import org.jsoup.*` will import `org.jsoup.nodes` but not `org.jsoup.nodes.Element;` because `org.jsoup.nodes.Element` lies in `org.jsoup.nodes` package.

example.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://www.google.com.hk/finance?q=0023&ei=yF14VYC4F4Wd0ASb64CoCw";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element content = doc.select("meta[itemprop=price]").first();
        System.out.println(content.attr("content"));
    }
}
```

output

```
31.40
```

edit

to know which classes you should import .....

consider this statement

```
Document doc
```

now you are creating Document object so you should import Document class .if you read [jsoup api](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html)  you can see this class hierarchy .

as you can see `Document` is a class of package `org.jsoup.nodes`
so you import class as `import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;`  .you have to read the api. anyway ides like netbeans,eclipse suggest you some classes to import that's easy and save time a lot.

[image]

Comment: How do you what to import ? Because I always do not know what packages to import ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF you can use a ide .ide suggest you what you need to import also you can read jsoup ..http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html .looking at class hierarchy you can understand what you should import